# android video frame does not fill screen on landscape

Tags: android, orientation

So I have this code, which is called onConfigurationChanged :

```
private void setVideoLayoutParams(){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        // this works as expected
        showNavigationAndStatusBars();
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size.x, size.x * 9 / 16);
    }else{
        hideNavigationAndStatusBars();
        // this does not work properly
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size.x, size.y);
    }
    controller.setPauseButtonSize();
    Log.d(TAG, "video layout params set : " + params.width + "/" + params.height);
    videoFrame.setLayoutParams(params);
}

private void hideNavigationAndStatusBars(){
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

}

private void showNavigationAndStatusBars(){
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

When the screen is rotated into landscape, the navigation and status bars disappear. However my videoFrame does not fill the screen.

A small portion on the right side of the screen remains blank and is equal to height of the navigation bar.
Another small portion on the bottom of the screen equal to the height of the notification bar remains blank.

When the params are created, my logger shows 1794/1080. When I touch the screen, I log the size of the videoFrame and it shows 1794/1009. My guess is it should show, in both cases, 1800/1080.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put your Videoview inside a Relative layout and add alignparentright, alignparentleft, alignparenttop and alignparentbottom "true". It will be perfect.

Comment: Try creating a landscape layout of the xml and do as i told. It works for me.

Comment: Didn't work either. Could it have something to do with the fact that I only remove the navigation and status bars in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is like this right?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And try

```
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
         params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
         params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
         params.leftMargin = 0;
         videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: it's match_parent instead of fill_parent, but other than that, yes